# Top Space TLabel or TStaticText Delphi

Tags: delphi, label, spacing, tlabel

I need my Label aligned to Top, but in the very top, in the first top pixel.
The property layout is already aligned to Top and I'm still getting this spacing.
For some reason, Delphi add an extra spacing. I can't have that.

[image]

Comment: You need to write code on SO, rather than showing us in an image.

Comment: The code we can see in the image doesn't add `alTop` to the `TStaticText`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text actually *is* lined to the top. To see that use some characters that actually reach the top like German Umlauts ÄÖÜ. In your example the letter T is just not big enough to reach the top.